# Change Content View Background?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I have my main view programmed to set a background image. Is it possible to do it with a content view as well? I have my content view on top of my main view so I can't see the background. I attached an image below. The blue is the "content views" background. I don't want to add an image view, just do the same as I did with the main view.[image]

Comment: Couldn't you set the color of the content view background to transparent (`UIColor.clearColor()`), which would show the background behind it?

Comment: And how would I do that in my code? Where would I do that in my code? Just placing it under my override func didn't work.

Comment: Considering you have an outlet to the view you selected in the above screenshot, add this line inside `viewDidLoad`. `subView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()` where `subView` is an example name of the outlet to the view mentioned.

Comment: Thank you!! If you answer, ill approve it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the discussion in the comments on the question. Setting the background of the view to transparent fixed the problem.

`subView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()` line added in `viewDidLoad` method where `subView` is the name of the outlet of the view.